# How do I get the .ToList to show when reading from a repository...Where am I going wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, layer

For some reason, C# wont show me the .ToList on my code. I am wondering how to get it.

I have a basic MVC4 app which I successfully divided into several projects as a proof of concept. So here are my layers...Everything works until I try to add a domain layer. This is where the confusion starts. So some code:

My model is generated from the database by EF5. I have a standard "Student" class with an ID and a Name. This is all. It relates to a course. A course has many students. Here is what EF Generates.

```
public partial class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateAttended { get; set; }  //This field becomes important later
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the course model.

```
public partial class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.Student = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; }
}
```

I extracted this out to a Models project and fully tested everything after. All went well, no problems there.

Then I added a generic repo layer between this and my controller to remove the DB access logic from my controllers. Here is the interface:

```
public interface IHeadRepository<TEntity>
{
    ICollection<TEntity> ReadAll(); //I Want to focus here for the problem...

    int Create(TEntity entity);
    TEntity ReadSingle(int id);
    ICollection<TEntity> ReadSome(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    int Update(TEntity entity);
    int Delete(TEntity entity);
}
```

I will only show the implementation of the part I want to focus on for brevity...

```
public class HeadRepo<TEntity> : IHeadRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;
    private readonly DbContext dbContext;

    public HeadRepo() { }

    public HeadRepo(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        dbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }


    public ICollection<TEntity> ReadAll()
    {
        return dbSet.ToList();
    }
}
```

Before I started trying to implement my domain layer, I tested everything and it all worked. So I proceeded to implement my domain layer and made a few changes to my repo.

Origionally both the interface and repo looked like this...

```
    public IQueryable<TEntity> ReadAll()
    {
        return dbSet;
    }
```

It was an Iqueriable instead of a ICollection. I tried all kinds of changes, IList, IEnumerable etc.

**Finally...The problem I am having seems to be with my controller...But I am aware that it could be because of the way I implemented the repo. However I don't know how to fix it.**

So here is my controller...The index action.

This is the before. It worked fine.:
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(studentRepo.ReadAll());
        }

What I am trying to do (and I know I could do this simple task in any number of places but I want to get it working here and extract it later) is add a ViewModel which has an extra field called something like YearsGraduated. Like this:

```
public class StudentVM : Student
{
    [Display(Name = "Years Graduated:")]
    public int YearsGraduated { get; set; }
}
```

Then I want to go to my controller and, use my repo to read all the students, assign the list of students to my list of studentVM's and then run a simple method on them to calculate the years since they graduated. So here it is in SemiSudo...

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //I get an error when I do this (the best overloaded...has invalid args)
        //var vm = new List<StudentVM>(studentRepo.ReadAll());

        //So I try this:
        //var vm = new List<StudentVM>();
        //vm = studentRepo.ReadAll(); //I get error here...Cannot implicity comvert...explisit exists

        //So I try this:
        //var vm = new List<StudentVM>();
        //vm = studentRepo.ReadAll().ToList(); //I get error here...No definition / extension method .ToList() can be found

        //So I tried updating my repo interface and changing it from:
        //IQueriable to ICollection
        //ICollection to IEnumerable
        //IEnumerable to IList
        //IList to List
        //Without any success.

        //As explained, if I can get this working, I would like to do something like:
        //
        //var vm = new List<StudentVM>();
        //vm = studentRepo.ReadAll();
        //For(i=0; i<vm.count; i++)
        //{
        //    vm[i].YearsGraduated = CalcYearsExpired(vm[i].DateAttended)
        //}


        //Some method outside this called CalcYearsExpired() which takes a date,
        //returns an int or double and im done.

        //Then the return method changes from this:
        //return View(studentRepo.ReadAll());

        //To something like this:
        //return View("Index", vm);

        //And the view changes accordingly to use the Collection<StudentVM> to list the students.
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...My goal would be to add a domain layer and extract this code when working so my controller stays simple. I am having great difficulty doing this so obviously there is no point in trying to do it elsewhere if I cant do it locally in the controller or repo first. I don't want to put it into the repo because it will make the repo to specific and I want to try keep it generic. But my priority is to resolve the problem so if I have to make the repo more specific I would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the namespace System.Linq if not?

Comment: I feel so dumb...I typed all that...Its crazy how you get so far into the advanced stuff that the basics kick your butt every time. I guess I should find a better way of remembering them. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers It happens at times.